# (Theme Toggle) How can I make className sync dynamically to active localStorage value from its key when toggled in React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

className "page" needs to be modified to "page light-theme" or "page dark-theme" on toggle through local storage key "theme-color" with values of light-theme and dark-theme.

The active key value does change in local Storage but updates only show if the pages is refreshed. I need the changes to sync on toggle

Page to be changed

```
    export default function Page({children}){

    return(
        <div className={`page ${localStorage.getItem('theme-color')}`}>
        {/* <div className= "page">  */}
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

h3 inner text needs to change dynamically depending on the active value from key "theme-color" in local storage. I have place the variable "themeOpener" in between h3 tag. No changes take place

heres is my code

```
export default function Body() {

    let themeOpener;

    if (`${localStorage.getItem('theme-color','light-theme')}`) {
        themeOpener = "Ahh the light it burns! Please use toggle, I prefer dark mode!";
    } else {
        themeOpener = "I learnt to design in React and im hooked ";
    }

    return (
        <div className="body">
            {/* <h3 id="opener">I learnt to design in React and im hooked </h3> */}
            <h3 id="opener">{themeOpener}</h3>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is code for my toggle where local storage is created

```
const ToggleMode = () => {
    // state
    const [isLight, setIsLight] = useState(false);

    // effect
    useEffect(() => {
        // check local storage
        const CurrentTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme-color");
        if (CurrentTheme === "light-theme") {
            setIsLight(true);
        } else {
            setIsLight(false);
        }
        console.log(useEffect);
    }, []);

    const ToggleChecked = () => {
        // logic
        if (isLight) {
            localStorage.setItem("theme-color", "dark-theme");
            setIsLight(false);
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem("theme-color", "light-theme");
            setIsLight(true);
        }
        console.log(ToggleChecked);
    };

    return (
        <div className="toggle--container">
            <input
                type={"checkbox"}
                id="toggle"
                className="toggle--checkbox"
                checked={isLight}
                onChange={ToggleChecked}
            />
            <label htmlFor="toggle" className="toggle--label">
                <span className="toggle--label-background"></span>
            </label>
            <div className=""></div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ToggleMode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is natural according to your code. Whenever toggling, `ToggleMode` component will only be re-rendered by changed state value `isLight`.

But your `Body` and `Page` component which are supposed to be `ToggleMode`'s parent will not be re-rendered. Because their `props` or `states` never changed by `ToggleChecked()`.

To get it done working, you need to do something to re-render parents in `Page` and `Body` component.

How? You need to create a state value in those components or create `IsLight` and `setIsLight` at the top level component. And then these two would be drilled into `ToggleMode`.

Something like followings.

```
export default function Page({children}){
    // state
    const [isLight, setIsLight] = useState(false);

    return(
        <div className={`page ${localStorage.getItem('theme-color')}`}>
        {/* <div className= "page">  */}
        <Body isLight={isLight} setIsLight={setIsLight} />
        
        {children}

        </div>
    )
}

export default function Body({isLight, setIsLight}) {
 
   return (
      <div>
          <ToggleMode isLight={isLight} setIsLight={setIsLight}  />
      </div>
   );
}

export default function ToggleMode ({isLight, setIsLight}){
   // This is not needed anymore.
   // const [isLight, setIsLight] = useState(false);

   return (<>Your toggle code...</>)
}
```

P.S. Don't you think this is quite irritating? To avoid prop drilling, we use state management utilities such as react context API or 3rd party libraries such as Redux.

Comment: lol yeah it is. Thats why I thought maybe I cold avoid that and rely on local storage, I guess not. Thanks for the advice I'll give react context API a try.

Comment: @Jordan, yeah context API is much easy to use!